# Runtime SIGSEV error

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

I am getting a SIGSEV fault while executing the program. If the numbers were listed in increasing order of their index then the group A would have every other one starting with the first number in the list and the group B would have every other one starting with the second number on in the list. However, certain numbers, as specified in the second line of each case are to be skipped. Then the numbers of the two groups are to be printed out.

The first line contains a single integer T ≤ 50 indicating the number of test cases to follow. Each test case consists of two lines. The first line contains two numbers n,m satisfying 0 ≤ m ≤ n ≤ 1000. Here, n is the highest number till which we run and m is the number the values to be skipped. The second line contains a list of m distinct integers between 1 and n. These are the number to be skipped. Consecutive integers are separated by a single space.

Eg:-
Input:

```
3
6 3
2 4 1
3 2
3 2
8 2
3 8
```

Output:

```
3 6
5
1

1 4 6
2 5 7
```

My code runs this case perfectly, and other cases where it accesses the end indexes too, but the website is not accepting the solution, with the specified fault appearing.
Please note that here I am trying to solve a practice coding site's question, hence the lack of checks, and that I am a beginner, so I don't have information regarding concepts like vectors, etc. 
The compiler is GCC14

Thanks in advance if you read up this huge question and do answer!

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  long cases, tasks, dones, t_done, i, k = 1;
  cin >> cases;
  for( int j = 0 ; j < cases ; j++ )
  {
    k = 1;
    cin >> tasks >> dones;
    int task[tasks] = {0} ;

    for( i = 0 ; i < dones ; i++ )
    {
        cin >> t_done ;
        task[ t_done - 1 ] = 1 ;
    }

    while(k <= tasks)
    {
        for( ; k <= tasks; k++)
        {
            if( task[k-1] != 1)
            {
                task[k-1] = 2;
                break ;
            }
        }
        k++;

        for( ; k <= tasks; k++)
        {
            if( task[k-1] != 1)
            {
                task[k-1] = 3;
                break ;
            }
        }
        k++;

    }

    for( i = 1 ; i <= tasks ; i++)
    {
        if(task[i-1] == 2)
            cout << i << " ";
    }
    cout << "\n" ;
    for( i = 1 ; i <= tasks ; i++)
    {
        if(task[i-1] == 3)
            cout << i << " ";
    }
    cout << "\n" ;
}
return 0 ;
}
```

Comment: Unable to compile. Variable length Array with initializer. I suppose that non-standard extension comes with a GCC in the 5s or 6s?

Comment: Replaced with vector and pasted in your sample inputs. Unable to duplicate.

Comment: It may be more useful to provide a backtrace (see http://www.unknownroad.com/rtfm/gdbtut/gdbsegfault.html)?

Comment: Your code would be much easier to read if your loops started from `0` instead of `1`, so you didn't have to write `k-1` and `i-1` all over the place.

Comment: I suspect the website doesn't like your use of the VLA `int task[tasks]`. If you can't use vectors, you can simply do `int task[1001;`.

Comment: VLAs work in the website. i have done other questions utilising it